# Getting 'undefined' when requesting data from API

Tags: javascript, json, html, api

Why am I getting 'undefined' when trying to pull specific data from Public API? What is wrong with below code?

```
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="gget();">Click</button>
<p id="MyDiv"> </p> </body>

<script>function gget(){
   var btc = new XMLHttpRequest();
   btc.open('GET', "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/", true);
   btc.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(btc.readyState == 4) {
          var data = JSON.parse(btc.responseText);
          var price = data.id;
          document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML = "$"+price;
    }};
    btc.send();
    } </script>
```

Comment: can you please paste your full error ?

Answer (score 0):

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/ returns an array containing 1 object.

You want to access `data[0].id` to access the ID of that first/only element. Price you're looking for is probably `data[0].price_usd`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jeto's answer, the code would look something like this, assuming you want the price in US dollars.

```
function gget(){
  var btc = new XMLHttpRequest();
  btc.open('GET', "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/", true);
  btc.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(btc.readyState == 4) {

      var data = JSON.parse(btc.responseText);
      var price = data[0].price_usd;
      document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML = "$"+price;
    }};
  btc.send();
}
```

In addition, you can provide feedback to the user in error cases.

```
function setPriceLabel(value){
  document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML = value;
}

function gget(){
  var btc = new XMLHttpRequest();
  btc.addEventListener("error", function(){
    setPriceLabel("Could not fetch price from server");
  });
  btc.open('GET', "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/", true);
  btc.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(btc.readyState == 4) {
        try{
          var data = JSON.parse(btc.responseText);
          console.log(data)
          var price = data[0].price_usd;
          setPriceLabel("$"+price);
        }
        catch(e){
          setPriceLabel("Server sent bad data");
        }
    }};
  btc.send();
}
```

The `btc.addEventListener` block will catch HTTP errors and set the price label to an error message.

In addition to HTTP errors, it is also possible for the JSON parse function to fail. Since `JSON.parse` is a synchronous function, we can handle its errors with try-catch syntax.